# How can I connect a DVI monitor to the VGA port in my laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, dvi, vga

Is there a device I can buy that will convert the analog signal to digital?

Answer (score 6):

You may find that a USB-to-DVI video adapter costs less than either a new monitor or a full-on VGA-DVI converter.

ex: [http://www.amazon.com/Diamond-BVU195-Display-Adapter-included/dp/B002GHBW4S/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1271951907&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GHBW4S)

This works best if you are using the laptop's external display primarily for office work, web browsing, or other non-intensive graphics applications.  I would not recommend it for 3-D gaming or for watching movies.

Answer (score 5):

There are, but they are quite pricey. For example:

[VGA to DVI Converter/Scaler](http://www.dvigear.com/vgatodvicosc.html)

[VGA / HDtv To Dvi-i Scaler / Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00083Y6YU)

[VGA to DVI Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00142ED38)

A simple VGA<->DVI adapter will work the other way (DVI output to VGA display).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it'll just be cheaper to buy a second cheap monitor then!  Makes me wonder why the hell Dell would put a VGA port on a new >$1000 laptop that has a discrete graphics card...

Comment: No HDMI port either?

Comment: DVI -> VGA assumes that the DVI port outputs a DVI-I or DVI-A signal.  Many cards do, but there are a few that are DVI-D only and require active conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there seem to be [Adapters available](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EDRZ0G).

Comment: That adapter will only work if the monitor accepts an analog signal over a DVI connector.  Most don't.

Comment: Yeah, I bought a similar $5 adapter and it did not work :(