# My monitor only has DVI ports, and my laptop only has VGA and HDMI ports

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi

Is there any way I can connect my laptop that only has VGA and HDMI ports to a DVI-only monitor?

Edit: The model is HP LP2065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use any adapter cable between HDMI to DVI. Then you use a cable to connect the display to the adapter cable.

To connect a DVI monitor to a VGA port on a laptop you will need a VGA-DVI converter. For more information about how to connect a DVI monitor to a VGA port on a laptop look at this question: [How can I connect a DVI monitor to the VGA port in my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/133707/how-can-i-connect-a-dvi-monitor-to-the-vga-port-in-my-laptop).

Answer (score -1):

VGA is compatible with DVI. That was part of the design of DVI, after all. You should avoid using the VGA port if at all possible because it's analog and lossy. You'll likely notice ghosting and other artifacts.

HDMI *may* be compatible with DVI, depending on your hardware. For example, AMD graphics cards ship with DVI-to-HDMI adapters. This only works because the hardware and software detect the change and speak in DVI protocol rather than HDMI.

For the definitive answer, ask HP.

Comment: "VGA is compatible with DVI" => technically correct, but not particularly useful. Most monitors with DVI ports have DVI-D ports, which only take digital input. A passive VGA-to-DVI adapter will only work if it takes DVI-A (analog) or DVI-I (both). Also, if you suffer any kind of loss from VGA at 1920x1080x32 (pretty standard resolution) over a short distance, then there's something else wrong: while digital tends to be better in more cases, in the common case it's impossible to notice a difference with the human eye.

Comment: I always notice loss at that resolution and distance. Typically ghosting is present, but ill defined edges are universal.

Comment: DVI and HDMI are both digital, last I heard (and I could be wrong, do tell me if I am) it is always possible to convert between the two of them.

Comment: DVI has an analogue mode that's essentially VGA with another connector type. As Bob mentioned, not all monitors support that mode.